# Express-session not setting cookie in production

Tags: node.js, express, redis, session-cookies, express-session

I'm using Redis Store to store my sessions since I use a serverless backend, and I'm running into problems to set my cookie.

My frontend and backend currently run on 2 different domains, and this is how I configured my session management:

```
app.use(json());
app.use(
    session({
      store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
      secret: options.sessionSecret,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PROD' ? true : 'auto',
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PROD' ? 'none' : 'lax',
      },
    })
  );
```

As said, the issue occurs when I'm in production, when I'm in development my cookie generates as expected.

Is my session configuration incorrect? Or missing something?
TIA!

Comment: is your application server is behind proxy ? if so please add app.set('trust proxy', 1); to your app.js.

Answer (score 0):

As @Brijesh mentioned, we should set a property to trust the proxy:

```
  app.set('trust proxy', 1)
  app.use(json());
  app.use(
    session({
      store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
      secret: options.sessionSecret,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PROD' ? true : 'auto',
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PROD' ? 'none' : 'lax',
      },
    })
  );
```